# What was the connector attribute 'backlog' renamed to?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

[Tomcat's 9 changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html) states the following

> Remove the undocumented support for using the old Connector attribute names backlog, soLinger and soTimeout that were renamed several major versions ago. (markt)

I am right now interested in the **backlog** attribute. I could not find anywhere what it was renamed to. Anyone knows what the new name is ?

Comment: [`acceptCount`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html). Rather a pointless change IMO. The new name is less meaningful than the old.

Comment: They should also have mentioned the new names in the change log. All three changes were poorly motivated IMO. They map directly to parameters in system calls that are called exactly the same thing.

Comment: For the record, `soLinger` became `connectionLinger`, and `soTimeout` appears to have become `connectionTimeout`. All three names are poorly chosen. `acceptCount` has to do with what happens *prior* to `accept()`; `connectionLinger` refers to what `close()` does, without making the slightest difference to the connection; and `connectionTimeout` refers to what `read()` does, again without affecting the connection in any way.